# Windows Server write access to Remote Desktop Local Resource from a different user

Tags: permissions, remote-desktop, windows-server

I have connected to a server using Remote Desktop and mounted a drive as a "LocalResource". The drive is visible as `\\tsclient\VpnFolder` on the server. I can read and write files from the server to this share using Explorer, so the logged-in user does have write permission.

I am now trying to write to the drive as a different user (Exchange Server Shell) and I am getting `Access Denied` errors.

How can I modify the permissions on `\\tsclient\VpnFolder` so that another user (in this case the Exchange Client) can write to it? (I am attempting to export some PST files.)

I am using Remote Desktop on MacOS connecting to Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\\tsclient` resource exists only within the security context of the user that logged in via Remote Desktop. It does not support configuring permissions or access by users outside the specific RDP  session.

Your workarounds are:

- Run your commands on the local server using the same account you're using to log in via Remote Desktop.
- Establish an alternate connection method from the remote machine to your local device, such as through a SMB/CIFS share or FTP.
- Grant the user you're using to connect via RDP permission to the data generated by the command you're running in another user context.